# Micropython updating board V 1.0

Tags: firmware, micropython

I'm trying to connect my PyBoard board to another device (No, I do not want a REPL. I have done that already) and I have the external device's USB Serial exchange wired up perfectly. However, the USB_VCP module for Micropython had not been added when I preordered my board, so I need to update the firmware. All the instructions tell me to connect the 3v3 pin to the DFU pin, but that isn't there for my board's version. Can I update, and if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pyboard version is 1.0 then boot0 pin is P1. If your pyboard version is 0.4 then boot0 pin is P2. Find version by looking at silkscreen on your pyboard. You can find the location of these pins at following docs:
https://github.com/micropython/pyboard/blob/master/PYBv10b.pdf
and
https://github.com/micropython/pyboard/blob/master/PYBv4.pdf
Look at second page of pdf docs.

After updating the firmware, you should proceed according to following instructions. (These are sent from Damien to me).

You need to do:

```
import pyb
usb_vcp = pyb.USB_VCP()
```

or:

```
from pyb import USB_VCP
usb_vcp = USB_VCP()
```

Alternatively, you can try using:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('text')
```

This will write text to the USB.